# postgres.app can't find database with my username

Tags: postgresql, postgres.app

When I click `Open psql` on the Welcome to Postgres window with the fancy blue elephant, it opens a terminal and I get this command and output:

```
Tyler-Singer-Clarks-MacBook-Pro:~ Tyler$ '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Version
/9.3/bin'/psql -p5432
psql: FATAL:  database "Tyler" does not exist
```

Why would this database exist or not exist? (I'm not really sure what is responsible for this database's existence, and thus where I should be looking in order to fix this issue)

EDIT:
and the Welcome window says "You now have a PostgreSQL server running locally." And it did not give me an error about not being able to use port 5432.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html

I uninstalled postgresql with `brew uninstall postgresql` and uninstalled Postgres.app by dragging the elephant from Applications to Trash and Emptying Trash. The key thing is to then follow the instructions in the above link and remove `~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres`. Only then did installing postgresql with `brew install postgresql` and Postgres.app with the installation instructions in that link finally work.

Classic, "Turn it off, turn it on" solution, but gotta do it fully and correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try executing `createdb Tyler` from the terminal.

PostgresApp is supposed to create a database with your user name during its setup. Apparently this sometimes fails and requires manual creation.

More info: [PostgresApp Issue #139](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/139)